# Stop line animation from run the whole web css

Tags: html, css, css-animations

I need the animation on my page to not float up the whole page but start from where the border above about me section.

[Code](http://%20https://codepen.io/Munch10/pen/yLbBVQZ)

Comment: Your link is broken but could you provide the code here as well so it is easier to help you out with it

Comment: I was gonna submit an edit but the queue is full, but basically edit the question and press `CTRL+M` and enter your code there instead of providing a codepen, ideally

Comment: Link to the codepen is: [link]https://codepen.io/Munch10/pen/yLbBVQZ but please put the code into the question - if possible as a working snippet we can try ourselves.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A realy simple way would be to give each light z-index: -1 so they don't show until they get above the white 'header'. But I don't know whether this is exactly the result you want or not.

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  height: 100vh;
  font-weight: 100;
  background: radial-gradient(#24c6dc, #514a9d);
  overflow-y: hidden;
  animation: fadeIn 1 1s ease-out;
}

.light {
  position: absolute;
  width: 1px;
  opacity: .50;
  background-color: beige;
  box-shadow: #07e7e7 0px 0px 20px 2px;
  opacity: 0;
  top: 100vh;
  bottom: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  right: 0px;
  margin: auto;
  z-index: -1;
}

.x1 {
  animation: floatUp 4s infinite linear;
  transform: scale(1.0);
}

.x2 {
  animation: floatUp 7s infinite linear;
  transform: scale(1.6);
  left: 15%;
}

.x3 {
  animation: floatUp 2.5s infinite linear;
  transform: scale(.5);
  left: -15%;
}

.x4 {
  animation: floatUp 4.5s infinite linear;
  transform: scale(1.2);
  left: -34%;
}

.x5 {
  animation: floatUp 8s infinite linear;
  transform: scale(2.2);
  left: -57%;
}

.x6 {
  animation: floatUp 3s infinite linear;
  transform: scale(.8);
  left: -81%;
}

.x7 {
  animation: floatUp 5.3s infinite linear;
  transform: scale(3.2);
  left: 37%;
}

.x8 {
  animation: floatUp 4.7s infinite linear;
  transform: scale(1.7);
  left: 62%;
}

.x9 {
  animation: floatUp 4.1s infinite linear;
  transform: scale(0.9);
  left: 85%;
}

@keyframes floatUp {
  0% {
    top: 100vh;
    opacity: 0;
  }
  25% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  50% {
    top: 0vh;
    opacity: .8;
  }
  75% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  100% {
    top: -100vh;
    opacity: 0;
  }
}

#about-me {
  display: flex;
  text-align: center;
  background: white;
  background-position: absolute;
  padding: 10em;
  margin-top: 20em;
}
```

```html
<div class="background">

  <button class="btn" href="#">Projects</button>

  <div class="light x1"></div>
  <div class="light x2"></div>
  <div class="light x3"></div>
  <div class="light x4"></div>
  <div class="light x5"></div>
  <div class="light x6"></div>
  <div class="light x7"></div>
  <div class="light x8"></div>
  <div class="light x9"></div>
</div>
<!-- <h1 id="logo">KaizenWB</h1> -->
<nav class="nav-flex">
  <div class="nav-link">
    <a class="page-link" id="#home" href="#">Home</a>
    <a class="page-link" id="#home" href="#">About</a>
    <a class="page-link" id="#home" href="#">Projects</a>
    <a class="page-link" id="#home" href="#">Contact</a>
  </div>
  </ul>
</nav>
<div id="about-me">
  <section>
    <h1>About me</h1>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Necessitatibus voluptatibus animi voluptates molestiae quis consectetur, non nostrum quaerat. Voluptate ipsum suscipit temporibus pariatur doloribus autem, commodi obcaecati esse molestias nam
      aliquid fuga tempora fugiat, exercitationem aliquam et quos dolorum quam! Corrupti unde laborum itaque reprehenderit quos recusandae quae a sequi.
    </p>
  </section>
</div>
```

Comment: Wow! Such a simple solution and I couldn't figure it out and it drove me crazy, thank you